# How to add a class number to a div with same number as cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

Cookie:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //hide all divs just for the purpose of this example, 
    //you should have the divs hidden with your css

    //$('.picture.1').hide();
    //check if the cookie is already setted
    if ($.cookie("currentDiv")===undefined){
            $.cookie("currentDiv",1);
    } else{ //else..well 
            //get and increment value, let's suppose we have just 8 divs     

            var numValue = parseInt($.cookie("currentDiv"));
            numValue = numValue + 1;
            if (numValue>8){
            //restart to 1
                $.cookie("currentDiv",1);
            }
            else{ //no issues, assign the incremented value
                $.cookie("currentDiv",numValue.toString());
            }

            //show the div
            $('.picture.'+$.cookie("currentDiv")).show();
            $('.current'+$.addClass(.cookie("currentDiv")); <--
    }
});
```

Div:

```
<div class="current"></div>
```

And then I set a style from 1 to 8 so if it is "current 1" it displays the number 1
How the cookie works: It sets a cookie if it isn't set yet and calls it 'currentDiv' and give it a number from 1 to 8 and refreshes the cookie if visited is larger as 8.
But how can I add that class to the div with this cookie/ jquery
It need to add a class because it will prevent browser data and I've an svg with numbers from 0 to 9

Thanks, Sake

Comment: The name of a css class is not allowed to start with a number (see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding class you should use something like this

```
$('.current').addClass($.cookie("currentDiv"));
```

But I would suggest you to add class with some name with it like

```
$('.current').addClass("cookie"+$.cookie("currentDiv"));
```

Having name which doesn't start with number is considered standard & should be followed strictly, while naming to `function`, `variable`, `class` or `file` even.